# Im having trouble understand this boolean logic. Can someone please explain it please

Tags: java, interface

The following is what I am having trouble understanding:

```
interface CheckPerson {
    boolean test(Person p);

public static void printPersons(
    List<Person> roster, CheckPerson tester) {
    for (Person p : roster) {
        if (tester.test(p)) {
            p.printPerson();
        }
     }
 }
```

I understand that this method is saying if true print person... however what I do not get is how does

```
boolean test(Person p);
```

work and what is it saying.

Perhaps if I understand this I can understand

```
if (tester.test(p)) {
            p.printPerson();
```

Thank you for your help... I'm still learning.

Comment: That isn't boolean logic.  That is an interface with a method that is a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you don't understand is why you can still call `test` when the method body for `test` is missing.

First you need to know that the `test` method is in something called an *interface*. Methods in interfaces generally don't have implementations (method bodies). Also you can't initialize an interface directly by calling its constructor. You can only create an instance of a class that implements the interface.

A class can *implement* an interface by saying:

```
public class MyClass implements CheckPerson {

}
```

And the class needs to provide the necessary methods (in this case, `test`).

```
public boolean test (Person p) {
    //implementation goes here...
}
```

Now let's look at your `printPersons` method. It takes a `CheckPerson` object and a list of persons. Now here comes the interesting part, when you want to call this method, you can't simply just:

```
List<Person> list = new ArrayList<> ();
list.add(somePersonObject);
CheckPerson.printPersons(list, new CheckPerson());
                               *****************
                               this part is wrong!
```

As I said before, an interface cannot be instantiated directly by calling its constructor, you need to instantiate a class that implements it and pass *that* to the method. You see, this is why `tester.test` works. Because `test` will always be a class that implements the interface and thus `test` will always have a body! Let's see this in action:

Let's create a class called `AdultTest`:

```
public class AdultTest implements CheckPerson {
    public boolean test (Person p) {
        return p.getAge() > 18;
    }
}
```

Note: I don't know what your `Person` class is like, so I made `getAge()` up. *Don't try to use it in your code if your person class doesn't have it.*

Now we can call `printPersons` without error:

```
CheckPerson.printPersons(list, new AdultTest());
```

And then it will print all the people whose age is greater than 18.

"But why should I create an interface to achieve this? Couldn't I just create a method that accepts a `AdultTest` object to test it?" you asked. That's a very good question!

The benefits of using interfaces is that you can easily expand its functionality. For example, I can create another class that tests if the person is a female:

```
public class FemaleTest implements CheckPerson {
    public boolean test (Person p) {
        return p.getGender().equals("Female");
    }
}
```

Again, `getGender` is made up.

Now you can just pass `new FemaleTest()` to the `printPersons` method!

If you don't create a new class for this, you need to create a new method that accepts a `FemaleTest` object, which is a lot of repeated code. Not good!

Answer (score 0):

**if (tester.test(p))**

This peace of code means:
You have an instance of **CheckPerson** named **tester**, and the class which implemented the **Checkperson** of which **tester** is an instance must have the logic to define test method which accepts **Person** object as parameter.

Now the return type of your **test()** method is a boolean, so in your if condition(**if (tester.test(p))**), based on the boolean value returned **true** or **false** it will either go into condition to print or it will not go inside condition if boolean value is false.

Note: if condition accepts boolean values i.e. true or false, so as your test() method returns a boolean value it is a valid expression.